# Eclipse Color themes does not change font color

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

I am using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 on a Macbook to work with a Fortran Project. I recently installed Color themes from the Eclipse marketplace. I can see the list of available color themes. If I select one and try to apply it, only the background and the line number change while the font color remains the default one. For example the image shows the editor with the Monokai theme (which on the preview looks very different), all other themes behave the same way. How can I make the color theme apply to the font too?

[image]

Comment: Which theme did you apply? Is it the font color or the font typeface that has not changed, or is it both. In the title you say color, but in the body it implies face? Which editor did it not work for, standard text, Java, etc? A few ideas: Could it be that the font specified within it is not available on your Mac? Did you restart the IDE after applying the theme?

Comment: I edited the question, hope it's clearer. By the way yes I restarted the IDE but that's not the problem.

Comment: Yes, with the extra info I was able to immediately identify the problem (I hope ;-). The key extra info you provided was the Fortran bit. BTW it would help in future questions if you provided in addition to the name, a link to which thing it is. For example there are many search results for "Color themes" on Eclipse marketplace, but none are an exact match, so I assume you meant https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme, same thing for Fortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the Fortran editor is not supported by the Eclipse Color Themes project (See editors list http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=editors)

Editor colours work in Eclipse by allowing (requiring!) the author of the editor plug-in gets to choose which colour is used by each element of their editor. When defining these colours, the editor author can choose to inherit some (all) colours from other editor's colours. The typical thing is to inherit the colours from some base elements, such as the standard text editor.

So in your case the Fortran editor inherits the background colour from something else (probably standard text editor), but provides its own colours for other things.

### Short term solution

To resolve this, you are going to need to specify the colours manually for the Fortran editor. Unfortunately I don't have the Fortran editor installed, so I will give you instructions for the Java editor and you can probably adjust accordingly.

There are two places (typically) to change individual colors, one is the *Colors and Fonts* preferences (under *General* -> *Appearance*).

[image: colors and fonts]

The other place is the *Syntax Coloring* preference for the specific editor. For example Java's is in preferences under *Java* -> *Editor*. Here you can see the syntax colouring pages for the editors I have installed at the moment.

[image: syntax color]

### Long Term Solution

File a feature request on Eclipse Color Themes github: https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme, or even better submit a pull request. If the Fortran editor you are using is Phortran, then there is already a request [See Issue 57](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues/57).

Answer (score 1):

To change Photran colors easyly, just edit the file:

$WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.photran.core.prefs

And just paste this (matches with a dark theme):

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
integer.fixedformcommentcolum=72
integer.tabwidth=0
rgb.comments=199,221,12
rgb.cpp=141,203,226
rgb.directives=141,203,226
rgb.identifiers=255,255,255
rgb.intrinsics=141,203,226
rgb.keywords=210,82,82
rgb.nums_punc=127,179,71
rgb.strings=255,198,0
string.modelbuilder=defaultModelBilder
```